# Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401) - XSLT

Tags: visual-studio

Just done a windows update and now visual studio wont debug XSLT files and complains

```
FileLoadException
-----------------
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

I've updated to the latest version of vs proffesional

17.9.2

any clues?

(this is reported elsewhere but not in connection with XSLT)

I've logged it with microsoft, but I dont hold out much hope getting a response in the near future

I believe the functionality broke when i installed

- KB5034763
- KB5034684

(I cant uninstall them)

Answer (score 0):

the problem evaporated.

I promise i didnt install anything, or even reboot (I had rebooted obviously before and it was still broken)

I'm guessing my solutions is so big that its taken visual studio an hour or two to work out that actually my XSLTs are fine after all in background.

Its a guess, but nothing seems to have changed, except it doesnt complain.